# Unable to integrate inside a summation with orthogonal functions in Sympy

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy, symbolic-integration

I am trying to do an integration of orthogonal function $ \sin(m \pi y) \sin(n \pi y) $ inside a summation. A little help would be very appreciated. The link for the jupyter notebook is [this](https://github.com/lemelinm/Maple-Documents/Laplace_equation%20en.ipynb). I am OK up to the input [42].

Comment: I've opened the notebook, maybe I'll be able to help later. Just to let you know, there is a simpler way to work with equations, which makes code much more readable: https://github.com/gutow/Algebra_with_Sympy

Comment: As a general SO tip some people (including myself) will ignore any question that does not include its content within the SO question page. Posting a link rather than writing your question here might mean that it gets ignored.

Comment: First, thank you Davide_sd for you GitHub. I will look into it with attention.  Second, thank you Oscar for the tips. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

First, as Oscar mentioned in the comment, you should provide the necessary code to replicate your issue, instead of hoping someone to actually go through 40+ notebook cells. This is how you do it: take the time to collect the necessary piece of code, like this:

```py
n, m = symbols("n, m", integer=True, positive=True)
x, y = symbols("x, y", real=True)
a, b = symbols("a, b")
C = IndexedBase("C")
expr = Sum(sin(pi*m*y/a) * sin(pi*n*y/a) * cosh(pi*b*n/a) * C[n], (n, 1, oo))
# problem here: it doesn't evaluate
integrate(expr, (y, 0, a))
```

Now to the answer: using the linearity of sums and integrals, we can swap the order of operations. With a bit of attention, we can do it manually:

```py
res = Sum(integrate(expr.args[0], (y, 0, a)), (n, 1, oo))
```

But now you would get a sum of a piecewise function. We can bring the summation into the pieces with:

```py
piecewise_fold(res).simplify()
```

Comment: Thank you again for the information. I have the manual sympy-docs-pdf-1.11.1.pdf but I find it very hard to learn. Do you know of a book on sympy as a good introduction?

Comment: Yep, I also faced a very steep learning curve with SymPy, that's why I wrote the book ["Symbolic computation with Python and SymPy"](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B09HJ1WZ7K/). It'll definitely bring you up to speed. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Well, your book just comes at the right time. Sold!